# How to displays item names from the database using a monthly or yearly chart PHP MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, chart.js

I am trying to make a chart by grouping the items by month and year. I was successful with just showing the item on the chart not name item. what I want is I want to retrieve data name item from my table.

This is my database and table structure:

| id (int) | item (varchar) | mydate (date) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | New | 2020-12-14 |
| 2 | Sold | 2020-11-16 |
| 3 | New | 2020-10-13 |
| 4 | Cancel | 2020-09-15 |
| 5 | Accepted | 2019-07-16 |
| 6 | Cancel | 2019-11-21 |
| 7 | Sold | 2019-08-29 |
| 8 | Delivery | 2020-12-22 |
| 9 | Delivery | 2018-11-14 |
| 10 | New | 2018-06-12 |

Here is just my short code chart.php:

```
<script name="bymonth">
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart_month");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: [<?php while ($row_month = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_month)) { echo '"'.$row_month['mydate'].'"';?>,<?php }?>],
        datasets: [{
                label: "item",
                data: [<?php while ($row_cmonth = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_cmonth)) { echo '"'.$row_cmonth['mydate'].'"';?>,<?php }?>],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
                    'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
        }
    }
});
</script>
<script name="byyear">
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart_year");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: [<?php while ($row_year = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_year)) { echo '"year '.$row_year['mydate'].'"';?>,<?php }?>],
        datasets: [{
                label: "item",
                data: [<?php while ($row_cyear = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_count)) { echo '"'.$row_cyear['mydate'].'"';?>,<?php }?>],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
                    'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Sorry, it's too long. for the full source file here:

https://www.mediafire.com/file/ah10eelxiweh2mn/chart.rar/file

On chart.php I only show item: (count) by month / year

How can i display the item name data of each date like.

```
December 2020

item:

New: 1

Delivery: 1

November 2020

item:

Sold: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query very poor and unreadable. If you are using too much if/else you are wrong way. Just use native functions.

PDO example;

```
$host = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$db_name = 'market_db';

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$db_name}", $username, $password);
$conn->exec("set names utf8");
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// trim for sql query, 01 -> 1
$_POST['month1'] = ltrim($_POST['month1'] ?: '1', '0');
$_POST['month2'] = ltrim($_POST['month2'] ?: '12', '0');

// By month

// only between months
if(isset($_POST['year1']) && $_POST['year1'] == null){
    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT *, MONTHNAME(mydate) AS month_name, YEAR(mydate) AS year, COUNT(*) AS item_count 
    FROM mytable WHERE MONTH(mydate) BETWEEN :month1 AND :month2 GROUP BY MONTH(mydate)");

    $query->bindParam(':month1', $_POST['month1'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindParam(':month2', $_POST['month2'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();
    $result_months = $query->fetchAll();
}
// between months with selected year
else {
    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT *, MONTHNAME(mydate) AS month_name, YEAR(mydate) AS year, COUNT(*) AS item_count 
    FROM mytable WHERE MONTH(mydate) BETWEEN :month1 AND :month2 AND YEAR(mydate) = :year1 GROUP BY MONTH(mydate)");

    $query->bindParam(':month1', $_POST['month1'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindParam(':month2', $_POST['month2'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindParam(':year1', $_POST['year1'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();
    $result_months = $query->fetchAll();
}
```

Then print as json array.

```
const byMonthData = [<?php foreach($result_months as $item) echo json_encode($item).','?>];
```

Use array map or filter.

```
labels: byMonthData.map(function (item) {
    return [
        [`${item.month_name} ${item.year}`],
        [`Item: ${item.item}`]
    ]
}),
```

Complete example

```
const byMonthData = [<?php foreach($result_months as $item) echo json_encode($item).','?>];

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart_month");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: byMonthData.map(function (item) {
            return [
                [`${item.month_name} ${item.year}`],
                [`Item: ${item.item}`]
            ]
        }),
        datasets: [{
            label: "item",
            data: byMonthData.map(function (item) {
                return item.item_count
            }),
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        },
    }
});
```

Result

[image]

Comment: I don't know how to use PDO. I've tried this, the chart don't even appear

Comment: @SctoDraig check this complete example, https://gist.github.com/EgoistDeveloper/5270791ff01bb2a63d22259bb2bdbe06